# get user's highest permission in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
@destiny.command(aliases=["ui, whois"])
async def userinfo(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):

  if user == None:

    user = ctx.author

  boosted = time.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I-:%M %p", user.premium_since.utctimetuple())
  created = time.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I-:%M %p", user.created_at.utctimetuple())
  joined = time.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I-:%M %p", user.joined_at.utctimetuple())
  members = sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m: m.joined_at)
  joinpos = str(members.index(user)+1)
```

i want to get the highest permission of {user} (highestperm =) but dont know how

Comment: Members have a [`top_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.top_role) attribute.

Comment: @3nws i need to get the highest permission of a user, not the highest role. lets say u have a hoisted role, and a perm role. if hoisted is above perm, it'll show the perms for the hoisted role and not the perm role

Comment: i might try getting it from ', '.join([str(p[0]).replace("_", " ").title() for p in ctx.author.guild_permissions if p[1]])

Comment: What do you mean by highest permission? Admin and ownership permisssions are not included in `guild_permissions` and it's not like the other permissions are in a hierarchy so you can determine the highest one as far as I know.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include desired and actual behaviour. See [ask] for more information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```py
' '.join([str(p[0]).title() for p in user.guild_permissions]).lower().split()[0]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).